# 開発用・申請用・テスト用等の環境単位のアプリ作成時、毎回UnityビルドからせずxCodeのビルド内容を変えることのみで各環境用のipaファイルを 作成したい。

Tags: unity3d, xcode

下記、知見をお持ちの方がいらっしゃれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

## やりたい事

JenkinsにてUnityビルド後に、JenkinsのxCodeの設定を変えて(シェルやxCode Pluginを使用等)、Unityで設定したBundle Identifierとは異なる名前にして、設定を変えたアプリが作成されるようにしたい。

## 目的

開発用・申請用・テスト用等の環境ごとのアプリを作成するときに、毎回Unityビルドから始まらないようにして、xCodeのビルド内容を変えることのみで各環境用のipaファイルを作成したい。

## やった事

ビルド用のMacBookに開発用・申請用・テスト用の証明書ファイルとプロビジョニングファイルを設定済み。

下記のことをJenkinsの設定で実行した：

1. Unityビルド処理。
2. 「シェルの実行」で指定した環境用のplistを、Unityがビルドで作成したplistに対して上書きコピーするためのcp 指定環境用 info.plist Unityを作成した。
3. xCodeのビルド設定をする。
4. ジョブを実行。
5. ジョブは正常に終了したが、xcodeでオープンしたところ指定したinfo.plistに変更されていた。

## 問題点

ProductNameを変更する方法がわかりません。
ProductNameを変更後のInfo PlistのBundle Identifierの後ろの文字を使用したいです。
ビルド完了後の○○.appと○○.dSYMファイルの○○の部分がUnityで設定したBundle Itentifierの後ろの文字のままでした。

## 環境

- MacBook Pro(2.8Ghz Intel Corei7)
- Unity 4.5.5f1
- Xcode 5.1.1
- Jenkins(xCode Plugin 1.4.5使用 Unity3d Plugin 0.6使用)

Answer (score 3):

試していないですが、以下のコマンドで変えられる可能性があります。

```
xcodebuild -target （ターゲット名） -configuration （Configuration名） build PRODUCT_NAME=プロダクト名
```

例：

```
xcodebuild -target MyApp -configuration Debug build PRODUCT_NAME=NewName
```